# Jquery inside observeEvents

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I am trying to use Jquery inside observeevent but not able to execute it.
The moment I click on "Release" button , the side bar should open. I have a Jquery here but not working. But when I put the same jquery inside onclick method, it works. But not in this method

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
actionButton("release", "Release"))
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

  useShinyjs()
  observeEvent(input$release,{
    tags$head(tags$script("$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-collapse');"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Using Shiny

Shiny ships with some jQuery/Bootstrap functions built in for convenience, `toggleClass` being one of them. To use it, move `useShinyjs()` somewhere into or after the `dashboardBody` (don't forget the comma), and replace your jQuery code with a call to `toggleClass`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),                                               ## <<<
    actionButton("release", "Release")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$release, {
    toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")  ## <<<
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

##### Using jQuery

You can also extend the available functions by adding custom ones (including jQuery calls just like yours) using `extendShinyjs`, and then invoke them using `js`. Prepend their name (e.g. `toggleCollapse`) with the `shinyjs.` prefix in the definition, and register them for later use with `js` in the `functions` argument.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),                                               ## <<<
    actionButton("release", "Release"),
    extendShinyjs(                                              ## <<<
      text = "shinyjs.toggleCollapse = function() {             // <<<
        $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-collapse');              // <<<
      }",                                                       ## <<<
      functions = c("toggleCollapse")                           ## <<<
    ),                                                          ## <<<
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$release, {
    js$toggleCollapse()                                         ## <<<
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you not call JQuery directly?

Comment: @manup You can define own JavaScript functions using `extendShinyjs`, and then invoke them using `js`. In your case, you could define one called `toggleCollapse`, for instance: `extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.toggleCollapse = function() {$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-collapse');}", functions = c("toggleCollapse")),`, and then invoke it within the observer: `observeEvent(input$release, {js$toggleCollapse()})`.

Comment: Invoking js should be on the server side right?

Comment: @manup Yes, as is your `observeEvent`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question here. We can make use of jq in UI only right? Meaning putting all these in server side shows the app right. As much as possible it’s better to write the JQ functions on the UI side right?

Comment: @manup Not that I know of. Calling a `shinyjs` function requires the Shiny `session` object, which is only provided for the server function: `server <- function(input, output, session) {…}`.

Comment: I tried with your code ````extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.toggleCollapse = function() {$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-collapse');}", functions = c("toggleCollapse"))```` and then ````observeEvent(input$release,{
    js$toggleCollapse()
})````. But did not work

Comment: @manup Hmm, looks fine to me. -- I have edited my response with fully self-contained scripts for both approaches. Please try running them.